# find index of an element present in second array from first array in android

Tags: java, arrays

get Index of element Which are common between 2 arrays

I have Two arrarys

array1[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
    array2 [] = {a, b, e, f, c, d};

I want to get the index of array2 based on elements from array1

the expected result is  0,1,4,5,2,3 how can we do this

Comment: Please don't use the Android tag for a question that has nothing to do with Android. Also, if you could please specify more clearly what programming language you are using, that'd would be great.

Comment: This is not question related Android!

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas, java

Comment: Well, update the tags then?

Answer (score 0):

Take each element from array1 and then search for the index of that element in array2.

Step 1:> Get one element at time from array1.

Step 2:>Then search for that element in array2 you will get the index.